# 3rd party software installations

Tags: software-center

Can you install 3rd party software on ubuntu?  We use microsoft office at my business and I word like to install it onto ubuntu to prevent any formatting problems at work.  Is this possible?

Comment: Have a look at the section about Wine in the top answer.

Comment: In general, microsoft office is going to be a bit buggy. You are better off using libreoffice or running ms office in a VM

Comment: To echo the comments of @bodhi.zazen. Linux is not Windows an in general while it is often possible to run Windows software with Wine it's less than ideal.  If you really need Windows software I would recommend you install Windows: either as a dual boot or in a virtual machine using Virtualbox or VMware. Alternatively LibreOffice is available for both Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 1):

There is something I saw a couple of days back on [http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/07/run-microsoft-office-web-apps-ubuntu-desktop), allowing the use of the MS Office web apps on Ubuntu.  I have a VM of Win8 installed, and run office that way, when I need to, but there is a .deb for installation in Ubuntu, or apparently a chrome link to the same set of apps.

Answer (score 0):

Although kingsoft office is visually identical, and supports the exact same files for free, you can install wine and run the full office suite, so long as it is 2010 or earlier, 2013 and 365 are not currently functional, and do not install